# C++ transferring a string between functions

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program for my course, where I have to make a random monster generator and then print the monsters' parameters.

I use this loop in `main`to generate and then print the data:

```
for (g=0; g < m; g++)
    {
        tab[g] = &createRandomMonster(g);
        printMonsterData(*tab[g]);
    }
```

This function for generating monsters:

```
 Monster createRandomMonster(int g)
{
    ostringstream buffer;
    buffer << ++g;
    string name = buffer.str();
    Monster nowypotwor{ name, MonsterType(rand() % 6 + 1), rand() % 25 + 5, (double)(10.0 + (rand() / (double)(RAND_MAX))*(30.0 - 10.0)) };
    return nowypotwor;
}
```

And this function for printing:

```
void printMonsterData(const Monster &potwor)
{
    cout << "potwor: " << potwor.name << endl << "typ: " << getTypeName(MonsterType(potwor.type)) << endl << "atak: " << potwor.attack << endl << "zycie: " << potwor.health << endl << endl;
}
```

I doesn't print the monsters' names though. It does if I `printMonsterData` in `createRandomMonster`, but doesn't if I do it in `main`, which I need to do.

Comment: You are taking the address of an rvalue, in this case the temporary returned from the `createRandomMonster` function. This causes undefined behaviour when accessing it later because the `Monster` has already been destroyed!

Comment: So how should I protect the string? All the generated numbers transfer correctly, it's just the strings that are the problem.

Comment: No it's not. Your monster is destroyed after this line `&createRandomMonster(g);` and you accessing memory that are no longer valid. But some of old data are still there and you can see them as a "echo". ps. Mixing Polish and English naming could be considered as bad style.

Comment: Perhaps you want to do something more like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be9cb40fd238bc8d)? Store your monsters in a vector and don't both trying to use pointers, its too error prone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the Monster return. ie, 
Monster aMonster = createRandomMonster(g); 
then you can say tab[g] = &aMonster.

EDIT-even with this solution, tab[g] will only be of utility for the life of the for loop, aka the life of aMonster. This is another consequence of operating by reference. You can get around this limitation if you declare a Monster in main's most outer scope, and return into that...

Is there any reason why tab is a Monster* array instead of a Monster array? It would make more sense to be the latter unless I'm missing something... especially since you immediately deference it to pass it to print by reference

Comment: I need the array size to be specified by the user.

Comment: The limitation of a static array doesn't change based on its contents. Whether you have a static (locally declared, stack allocated) array of values or an array of pointers, you need to know the quantity at compile time. If the array is dynamically allocated, you can create an array of Monster of a runtime quantity just the same as one of Monster*.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
tab[g] = &createRandomMonster(g);
```

`createRandomMonster` returns `Monster` class instance by value, so what it returns is a temporary object which is destroyed right after the end of full statement (which is after semicolon `;` character). So if you take address of this temporary object with `&`, you are actually taking address of a temporary which is very soon destroyed and you put in `tab[g]` a dangling pointer causing Undefined Behaviour in your later code execution.

I would suggest you dont store your `Monster` objects as pointers in `tab`, but by value:

```
std::vector<Monster> g;
```

if you need pointers then store them as:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Monster>> g;
```

and change `createRandomMonster` to:

```
 std::unique_ptr<Monster> createRandomMonster(int g)
{
    ostringstream buffer;
    buffer << ++g;
    string name = buffer.str();
    std::unique_ptr<Monster> nowypotwor = std::make_unique<Monster>(name, MonsterType(rand() % 6 + 1), rand() % 25 + 5, (double)(10.0 + (rand() / (double)(RAND_MAX))*(30.0 - 10.0)));
    return nowypotwor;
}
```

and:

```
tab[g] = createRandomMonster(g);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make the function createRandomMonster return a pointer to Monster (Monster*), or better yet, change the "tab" to hold a smart pointer (eg. shared_ptr) instead of a normal pointer, and return that from the function.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Monster>> tab;

std::shared_ptr<Monster> createRandomMonster(int g)
{
    ostringstream buffer;
    buffer << ++g;
    string name = buffer.str();

    return std::make_shared<Monster>(name, 
        MonsterType(rand() % 6 + 1), rand() % 25 + 5, 
        (double)(10.0 + (rand() / (double)(RAND_MAX))*(30.0 - 10.0)));
}

for (g=0; g < m; g++)
{
    tab[g] = createRandomMonster(g);
    printMonsterData(*tab[g]);
}
```

If you do not need to have polymorphic behaviour, it is best to hold values in the vector and copy the rvalue to tab:

```
std::vector<Monster> tab;

for (g=0; g < m; g++)
{
    tab[g] = createRandomMonster(g);
    printMonsterData(tab[g]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Transferring a string to a function can follow either of the two ways mentioned below:

1) C style - Declare an array (static/global/local) and pass the address (or reference as in C++) of it to the called function as a pointer. If dynamically allocated, pass the pointer instead

2) C++ style - Use std::string which will perform all the widening (if needed) which shall be good and no need to worry about writing off the bounds and works like a magic when you return from the function or perform equality later